# ng-option with ion-list item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am calling data from a web service and want to display the data in two ways. the first way is through a select/dropdown list which I have already done and it is working. The other way is to display it with an ion-item as a list, I have used the same coding for both so it should work. I have no errors and and the data for the ion-item does show in my console log so this tells me it is an issue of displaying it in html.

**HTML:**

**Select/Dropdown:**

```
 <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Quote:
    </div>
    <select ng-model="selectedrep1" ng-init="selectedrep1()" ng-change="TruckData(selectedrep1)" ng-options="rep1.QuoteNumber for rep1 in rep1s">
       <option value=""></option>
      <option selected>Select</option>
    </select>
   </label>
```

**Ion-Item**

```
<ion-list ng-model="selectedtruck1" ng-options="truck1.TrucksName for truck1 in truck1s">
  <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-value="">
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-repeat in ionlist, detailed example is given [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/)

```
<ion-list >
  <ion-item ng-repeat="truck1 in truck1s" 
    <h2>{{truck1.TrucksName}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Ok yeah that works thanks! I will accept the answer as soon as it will allow me to.